# $nuxt is not defined when using $nuxt.route in computed

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm looking to use the following for my `nuxt` routes within the computed property. All seemed to be working until 3mins ago when I started getting `$nuxt is not defined`. Removing the following code makes the app run again. What am I doing wrong here?

```
computed: {
    updateActiveRoute() {
        return $nuxt.$route.params.name ? $nuxt.$route.params.name : 'Hello'
    }
},

watch: {
    updateActiveRoute(newVal) {
        this.activeRoute = newVal
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$nuxt`, precisely `window.$nuxt` is only available on client-side and should **only be used as escape hatch**.

You can access the route object via `this.$route` instead when using the Options API.

```js
computed: {
    updateActiveRoute() {
        return this.$route.params.name ? this.$route.params.name : 'Hello'
    }
},

watch: {
    updateActiveRoute(newVal) {
        this.activeRoute = newVal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.$nuxt`

Only within the template you can access variables without this.